# WSL2 Node: npm install cpu-features -> npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: cmake: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, wsl-2

I have a react project that works fine. `node` (v14.17.0) and `npm` (7.19.1) is installed with `nvm`.

Installing packages with npm is fine e.g. for ssh2 but installing it, it does not install optional package `cpu-features` https://github.com/mscdex/cpu-features

When running `npm install cpu-features` i get error `npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: cmake: Permission denied`

Whole error message:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features/build'
npm ERR!   ACTION Configuring dependencies /mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features/deps/cpu_features/build/Makefile
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ilkkae/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ilkkae/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ilkkae/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! make: Warning: File 'cpufeatures.target.mk' has modification time 0.11 s in the future
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: cmake: Permission denied
npm ERR! make: *** [config_deps.target.mk:13: /mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features/deps/cpu_features/build/Makefile] Error 127
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/ilkka/Projects/draganddrop/node_modules/cpu-features
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have tried to transfer all files to wsl side so not mnt folder, running with `sudo` and it causes the npm install to hang and is not recommended anyways.

I also tried running as root user.

I am wondering why do I get premission denied error message. The files and folders are not root user/group.

Comment: try `sudo npm install cpu-features`

Comment: @Mikhail It just hangs, and also does not use the npm which was installed with nvm but rather what is installed with ```sudo apt install npm``` and it is older version (npm@6.14.4). When I'm running without ```sudo``` it is using the ```/home/ilkkae/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0``` which is v7.19.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed `cmake` module in the Linux. It won't not get installed with build-essentials. This is how I got rid of the same error.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @Artoiss's answer, if you are a Mac user who suffers with this problem just like me, you can easily install it using Brew;

```
brew install cmake
```

*If you don't have Brew installed in your Mac yet, have a look to here [Home Brew - Installation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)*

Answer (score 0):

**cpu-features** requires CMake according to their (npm) documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpu-features#requirements

This can be installed locally a number of ways. For example with a mac:

```
brew install cmake
```